# (Soft Question) Why does the Legendre Symbol apply only to odd primes

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, quadratic-residues

Why does the Legendre symbol, $(\frac{a}{p})$, apply only to odd primes $p$; and thusly the Jacobi symbol only to odd numbers? Are there any similar identities that hold for $p=2$?

Answer (score 2):

$\mod 2$, $1$ is a quadratic residue trivially.

The Legendre symbol applies only to odd primes since its explicit definition does not make sense for $p=2$:

$(\frac{a}{p}) \equiv a^{(p-1)/2}$.